# Error: Cannot find module 'moment' in the render deployin nodejs server file

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, deployment, server-side

solve this problem and run **npm i moment i** in the place of **npm i** or **npm install**
**Error Encountered:**

While deploying a Node.js server on Render, you're encountering the error "Cannot find module 'moment'." This indicates that the `moment` module, used for date and time manipulation, is either not installed or not accessible within the deployment environment.

**Resolving the Issue:**

1. **Install `moment`:**

   - Access the terminal within your project's root directory.
   - Execute the following command to install `moment` locally:

     ```bash
     npm i moment
     ```

     This ensures the module is included in your project's dependencies.
2. **Verify Installation:**

   - Check if `moment` is now listed under "dependencies" in your `package.json` file.
   - Confirm its presence within the `node_modules` folder.
3. **Deployment Considerations:**

   - Render's build process might not automatically include `node_modules`.
   - To ensure `moment` is available during deployment, run `npm i moment i`.
     This flag typically includes devDependencies for deployment.

**Additional Troubleshooting Steps:**

- **Typos:** Double-check for any typos in the `require` statement importing `moment`.
- **Cache Clearing:** If the issue persists, clear the npm cache using `npm cache clean --force` and reinstall `moment`.
- **Development Server:** Restart your development server to reload dependencies.
- **Module Location:** If `moment` is installed in a non-standard location, provide the correct path in the `require` statement.
- **Version Compatibility:** Ensure `moment` is compatible with your Node.js version.

**Request for Further Information:**

For more tailored assistance, please provide the following:

- Relevant code snippet from `index.js`
- Your project structure
- Any additional error messages or logs

**Remember:**

- Avoid global installations of `moment` to prevent version conflicts.
- If you have any further questions or require additional guidance, feel free to ask!

Comment: It appears you are trying to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). I suggest that you first get acquainted with how this website works by taking the [tour] and visiting the [help].